# Validity of Sec 309 of IPC (criminalization of suicide)

Tags: criminal-law, india, suicide

Section 309 of IPC (Indian Penal Code) criminalizes suicide as following —

> Whoever attempts to commit suicide and does any act towards the
> commission of such offence, shall be punished with simple imprisonment
> for a term which may extend to one year or with fine, or with both.

But according to Mental Healthcare Act of 2017 —

> Notwithstanding anything contained in section 309 of the Indian Penal
> Code, any person who attempts to commit suicide shall be presumed,
> unless proved otherwise, to have severe stress and shall not be tried
> and punished under the said Code.

So after considering both provisions —

- What actually are the practical consequences of suicide in India? And what actually courts do or do cases even go in courts?
- On whom will the onus be to prove mental condition of *accuse* to get section 309 of IPC prevail?